# Remove Data and Arraylist looping

Tags: java

I have a object with 3 variable (id(string), year(int), pay(double))
I have created an arraylist that contains object.

So now I need to sum the the pay if they have the same id and year and store it in a new array! is that possible?

```
   ArrayList<Earning> temp = new ArrayList();
ArrayList<Earning> temp = new ArrayList();

    double tempEarning = 0.0;
    int count = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < weeklyEarnings.size(); i++) {
        Earning e = weeklyEarnings.get(i);
        String id = e.getId();
        int year = e.getYear();
        tempEarning = e.getEarning();

        Earning e2 = weeklyEarnings.get(i + 1);

        if (id.equalsIgnoreCase(e2.getId()) && year == e2.getYear()) {
            tempEarning += e2.getEarning();
        } else {
            Earning tempEarn = new Earning();

            tempEarn.setEarning(tempEarning);
            tempEarn.setId(id);
            tempEarn.setYear(year);

            temp.add(tempEarn);

            count++;


            tempEarning = 0.0;


        }

    }

    weeklyEarnings.clear();
    weeklyEarnings = temp;
    temp.clear();
```

Can someone Help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
HashMap<String, Earning> totalEarnings = new HashMap<String, Earning>();
for (Earning earning : weeklyEarnings) {
   Earning tmpEarning = totalEarnings.get(earning.getId() + earning.getYear());
   if (tmpEarning == null) {
      tmpEarning = new Earning();
      tmpEarning.setId(earning.getId());
      tmpEarning.setYear(earning.getYear());
      totalEarnings.put(earning.getId() + earning.getYear(), tmpEarning);
   }
   tmpEarning.setEarning(tmpEarning.getEarning() + earning.getEarning());
}

for (Earning earning : totalEarnings.values())
{
   System.out.println(earning.getId() + ' ' + earning.getyear() + ' ' + earning.getEarning());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

1. Iterate through the list.
2. Match each item in the list with one id.
3. If match found "Sum Pay".
4. Continue for each item in the list.

Comment: can you elaborate further cause I am quite lost at this! Thanks!